Atomic transactions and optimizing query for high throughput
I'm writing a system for applying discounts to invoices. This involves a table which stores the codes which can be used and how much discount to apply.
Our application is split up in multiple workspaces, which means that each table has a column for workspace_id. We also have a wildcard workspace, *, which stores configuration that applies to all workspaces.
Tables
CREATE TABLE discount (
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  workspace_id character varying NOT NULL,
  display_name character varying NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "discount_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

-- we need the discount and discount_code separation because there
-- are more tables that build onto discount

CREATE TABLE discount_code (
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  workspace_id character varying NOT NULL,
  discount_id uuid NOT NULL,
  code character varying NOT NULL,
  valid_from timestamptz NOT NULL,
  valid_until timestamptz,
  amount integer NOT NULL,
  max_uses integer,
  CONSTRAINT "discount_code_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

ALTER TABLE "discount_code" ADD CONSTRAINT "discount_code_discount_fk"
  FOREIGN KEY ("discount_id") REFERENCES "discount"("id")
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

CREATE TABLE discount_use (
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  workspace_id character varying NOT NULL,
  discount_id uuid NOT NULL,
  discount_code_id uuid NOT NULL,
  invoice_id uuid NOT NULL, -- ignore the FK for now
  CONSTRAINT "discount_use_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

Problem: conflicts during inserts
When someone creates a discount code, we start a transaction in which we validate if there isn't any other code that overlaps with the current code:
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM
  discount_code
WHERE
  (workspace_id = '*' OR workspace_id = $workspace_id) AND
  code = $code AND
  (
    tstzrange(valid_from, COALESCE(valid_until, 'infinity')) &&
    tstzrange($valid_from, COALESCE($valid_until, 'infinity'))
  )

Note: if we want to add a global discount code, we skip the workspace_id check
If the count is greater than 0, we have overlap, which we want to prevent. In my understanding, running this in a transaction would still allow two concurrent queries to run and insert the same code, which would violate the application-level check.
If we have two queries running at the same time, both with a different workspace_id, it should allow the same code to be used.
The process of adding new discount codes is rather simple, but there could be a scenario where we need to dynamically generate a lot of codes at once, which all individually might start their transaction, and if our code generator would generate conflicting codes, it would gladly accept this.
To my knowledge, we can't use the Postgres EXCLUDE constraint, because we can only set it up to check against duplicates where the workspace_id matches, and not matches the same value or *.
We could change the transaction isolation level to lower the chance of conflicting information, but this would mean that in the case of 1000s of codes being generated at once, we'd run into a lot of transaction errors, which means we have to retry, which potentially could exhaust the connections in the pool / cause timeouts.
Problem: locking and high throughput with updates
When a discount code is created, it can either be unique for one customer, or one code that can be used by a lot of customers at the same time. During a sale, we might have hundreds of people who try to use the same code at the same time.
If we configure a maximum amount of uses on the code, we need to check if this limit has been reached, and we do not want to allow it to exceed that amount.
INSERT INTO discount_use (workspace_id, discount_id, discount_code_id, invoice_id)
SELECT
  workspace_id,
  discount_id,
  id AS "discount_code_id",
  $invoice_id AS "invoice_id
FROM
  discount_code
WHERE
  id = $discount_code_id AND
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM discount_use
    WHERE discount_code_id = $discount_code_id
  ) < max_uses
RETURNING *;

We want to prevent exceeding the amount of uses, how would we efficiently lock this down to stay atomic?
Problem: once a code has been used, cannot be modified
If we want to modify the config of a code, we only allow this if the code has not been used yet.
In our transaction, we count all the rows in discount_use for our $discount_code_id, and if it is > 0, we throw an application level error.
How can we efficiently lock this operation, so that no one can use a discount during an update, but also not update a discount while the discount is in the process of being used?

There are too many problems in a single question, but I'll focus on the first one. Perhaps then the others will become moot.
You could create an exclusion constraint like this:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;

ALTER TABLE discount_code
   ADD EXCLUDE USING gist (
      text_range(
         NULLIF(workspace_id, '*'),
         NULLIF(workspace_id, '*'),
         '[]'
      ) WITH &&,
      code WITH =,
      tstzrange(valid_from, valid_until) WITH &&
   );

The text_range data type I am using here is defined like this:
CREATE TYPE text_range AS RANGE (
   SUBTYPE = text,
   COLLATION = "C"
);

That should guarantee that no overlapping discount codes can be entered. The trick is that I turn the special workspace * into an infinite range and all other workspaces into single-element ranges. That way, the "overlaps" operator && does just what you want.

Why is the workspace_id in there twice? Does it take the value from the 2 rows it is comparing? Just for reference: workspace_id = 'a', code = 'a' is allowed to coexist with workspace_id = 'b', code = 'a', but workspace_id = '*', code = 'a' isn't allowed to coexist with those previous ones (ignoring the date for now)

Oh I see what you mean, the range with both nulls will basically create an infinite range which will overlap with everything, right? Now another layer to the problem: there's a column called is_case_sensitive. If the column is false, it should match on LOWER(code) and enforce uniqueness that way. If its true, it should check for any other row with it to false and LOWER(code) matches the current code, or another row that exactly matches. Would that also be possible with ranges?

Sorry, I didn't see the code. I fixed the answer. There is no is_case_sensitive in the question. Feel free to adapt the expression to include a conditional call to lower(), although I have to say that your requirements are getting a bit silly.

We have to support a range of different inputs from different sources and are constrained to some limits from external systems too. I know there is no is_case_sensitive in the question, as I didn't want to make the question even more complex.
